# for statement loop lowercase output

Tags: javascript

Add a for statement loop that prints all lower case characters:

```
var sOne = '';    // scratch variable

// for statements
console.log("\n..for..\n");
for ( i = 65; i <= 90 ; i += 1) {     
   sOne += String.fromCharCode(i);
};
console.log("sOne is: ", sOne);
```

The Output -
    sOne is: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

This is probably really basic but if you could explain it on a very remedial level that would be wonderful.

Comment: The upper-case letters are 65 through 90. Lower case are 97 through  122.

Comment: You can type `"a".charCodeAt(0)` in your browser console to see what the code is of a particular character.

Comment: Got it, so simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASCII code of lowercase letter start from 97-122. So if you set your i value range from 97 to 122 and it would print all lower case alphabet. It would be something like this.

```
var sOne = '';    // scratch variable

// for statements
console.log("\n..for..\n");
for ( i = 97; i <= 122 ; i += 1) {     
   sOne += String.fromCharCode(i);
};
console.log("sOne is: ", sOne);
```

Comment: what if I wanted this code block to return both the list of letters and their corresponding index number?

Comment: @CaitlinRyan I am not sure, But i guess you mean Unicode at each index.
You can use for loop to iterate over each  item in sOne. Then Use the  str.charCodeAt(index) method to get its unicode at specific index.

Comment: var sOne = '';    // scratch variable
var LetterIndex = []

// for statements
console.log("\n..for..\n");
for ( i = 97; i <= 122 ; i += 1) {     
   sOne += String.fromCharCode(i);
  
};
 for(var j=0 ;j<sOne.length;j++){
    LetterIndex.push(sOne.charCodeAt(j))
 }
console.log("LetterIndex is: ", LetterIndex);